# Windows service stuck in 'starting' state and difference between Thread.Sleep() and Task.Delay()

Tags: c#, task, threadpool

my windows service was stuck in starting state. Below was the code inside `onstart()`.`log()` will log some value to a file.

```
while (true)
        {
            log();
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
        }
```

after some experiments i changed `onstart()` to

```
while (true)
        {
            log();
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

once i changed the code service state changed to running and works fine.
What is the difference between Thread.Sleep() and Task.Delay() i thought both are delaying execution. Can anyone help me to understand

Comment: In `OnStart` you'd never want to have any of both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thread that calls `OnStart` *isn't* yours to do with as you will. It's actually used to respond to Service Control Manager requests directed to your service. Your service isn't considered started until you *return* from `OnStart`.

The key difference between `Thread.Sleep` and `Task.Delay` is that the first *blocks the current thread*, whereas the second, (if used with `await` and not for a delay of 0) will end up *releasing* the current thread.

Once you've added `async`/`await` to your `OnStart` method, you actually return from the method at the first point in execution where the code encounters an `await` on something that's not finished yet - your `await Task.Delay`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend having a `System.Timers.Timer`, in which `Elapsed` event you'd do the work of logging. In `OnStart` you simply start the timer, while `OnStop` you clean up (`Stop` and `Dispose` the timer).

About `Delay` vs `Sleep` considerations. Easy way to remember difference is to notice, that `Delay` reutns a `Task`, so it will be run asynchronously (so execution **won't be stopped**) if not `await`ed. `Thread.Sleep` on contrary, blocks current thread.